# how do i export multiple .fbx, with one material, and one texture map?

Tags: materials, unity, development, .fbx

i’m using blender to create a bunch of assets for a mobile game in Unity.
Sometime ago we adquired the Sinty Studio´s Simple Port assets, and I realize that they use only one material, and one texture for all the assets, with separate meshes for every object.

[image]

How can I do the same that Sinty does with my own assets(have multiple uvs, on multiple objects, but just one material and one texture)? I need to create different .blend archives? If so, how can I use the same material for each one of the different archives?

Exporting on fbx was a kind of solution, cause now I have my meshes separated and still with only one material, and one texture. But the method I used was to elaborate, cause I have to delete two of my three objects in the .blend, then export the .fbx, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> twice, and repeat whit another object. I don’t believe that´s the most efficient method, and since blender has a limited amount of undos, It won´t allow to do the process with has many objects as Sinty´s package has in a row. (sinty´s package has 84 models)

[image]

On other hand, i think another method will be to model every object in their own .blend, then have a *material-and-texture-mapping.blend* to pass every object trough, manually adjust the uv map, assign the material, and export from there in order to keep the one-material-one-texture-many uv's thing I’m looking for, but then again, I think that’s to elaborate, do you think of another way to solve that particular issue? it is an atlas-related problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simple way is to have all your model in one .blend, which share their unique material, and export one by one with *selected only* checked.

[image: blender selected only fbx export]

Then in Unity, you just have to set this in all your models setup :
[image: unity detect already exist material]

Unity will know that material allready exist, so it will be instanciate.

Unless you work in team, so you want one .blend by models : obviously you have all to use the same naming convention for the material, and with the same option in unity import above, it will probably works.

Comment: It worked smoothly, thanks a lot, you save me a lot of headaches!! :D